# How to convert specific date to its UTC (not the current date, a specific one)?

Tags: javascript, date

I want to fetch records from server in specific date, but current location is GMT +2 and server is UTC (GMT+0). So I should send the server either a translated date or a date with my timezone so he will calculate it by it self.

Doing this:

```
new Date().toISOString()
```

Will works only when not specifying a date - if do specifying, it doesn't:

```
new Date('2021-03-01').toISOString() // 2021-03-01T00:00:00.000Z
```

As you can see I receive this: **2021-03-01T00:00:00.000Z**
and my GMT is +2, so I actually should receive **2021-02-28:22:00.000Z** or something.

Comment: What does your server accept as input? A timestamp? A date? Does it accept a timezone specifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you've used `"2021-03-01"` is parsed as an ISO Date string in the UTC timezone (as if it were `"2021-03-01T00:00:00.000Z"`) in accordance with the [specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#Timestamp_string) for `Date`. The following line is the expected behaviour:

```
new Date('2021-03-01').toISOString() // 2021-03-01T00:00:00.000Z
```

If you want to convert a date from your system's local time to UTC, you need to either change your input string format so that it isn't parsed as the ISO format (e.g. `"MM/DD/YYYY"`) (not advised, expect inconsistency between platforms) or pass in the date parts as [separate arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#Individual_date_and_time_component_values) to the constructor.

```
new Date("03/01/2021"); // normally parsed as March 1st 2021 in local time
new Date(2021, 2, 1);   // always parsed as March 1st 2021 in local time
```

When the input date is parsed correctly in local time, the output is as you expect.

```
new Date(2021, 2, 1).toISOString() // 2021-02-28T22:00:00.000Z
```

Answer (score 0):

does this do what you need:

```js
const date = new Date('2021-03-01');
date.setHours(new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / 60);
```